# That's a lot of 'pizza'!

Tags: word-usage, idioms

I've heard this expression on TV suggesting '*a lot/(too)big amount of something*'.

It was from an experienced financial analyst (Bloomberg TV) who was referring to the big assets of a company. "There is a lot of pizza there". The guy who said that on TV was about 60. The part of the expression that I want to learn more about is the use of 'pizza' to refer to a big amount of something else.

Is it just an extension of the expression [that's a lot](http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=That%27s%20a%20lot)?

Is it a common expression (AmE or BrE) or just a one-off saying I happened to hear?

Comment: "That a lot of [something]" predates the slang.

Comment: @deadrat - you mean you are familiar with the expression?

Comment: Sure.  From my favorite mystery writer, Raymond Chandler: "**That's a lot of jack** but this Regan might be the boy to have it around...." *The Big Sleep*, 1939.

Comment: I'm confused.  What is unusual about saying "That's a lot of pizza" (or cow manure or people or thimbles or what-have-you)?  It's a perfectly normal, logical construction.

Comment: (The phrase was used as a tag line by a pizza chain maybe 20-30 years ago, but there was nothing "new" about it.)

Comment: That UD entry has 4 upvotes and 5 downvotes, and I don't recognize the usage as any kind of "idiomatic slang", so I wouldn't take any notice of it anyway.

Comment: @HotLicks - the 'unusual' part of the sentence is the use of 'pizza' to refer to 'a big amount of something' else.

Comment: @Josh61 Never heard of such a thing: *pizza* isn’t a generic.

Comment: @Josh61 -- Who said that "pizza" is being used to mean a generic "something"?  Pizza is pizza.

Comment: @Hot Licks - no prob. You just misunderstood the question!

Comment: So what was the question?  I took it to be asking if "that's a lot of ..." was some idiom with a hidden meaning.  It's not -- it just means that's a whole bunch of whatever.

Comment: If you explicitly heard "That's a lot of pizza" (you don't mention "pizza" in your question, except in the title), that could be referring to the ad tag line linked by chasly below.  It became something of an idiom, but had it's day decades ago.

Comment: @Hot Licks--- finally you are with me. So it was a slang expression!! The guy who said that on TV was about 60. It makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, everyone was saying it for about three weeks.

Comment: And someone still is!!!

Comment: Just to be clear, this question isn't asking about the meaning of "that's a lot of [something]" but specifically the exact phrase "That's a lot of pizza," correct?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - Yes!!!!! Is it really so unclear? Sorry for that.

Comment: Add context, where did you hear this phrase, what was said before and after. Was it on TV, or in the middle of the street etc..

Comment: My BF sometimes says "Datza spicy meat ball", and I'd just look at him bewildered. Apparently it was a TV commercial catchphrase , anything that is "good" can be answered with that expression. http://www.retroist.com/2012/07/09/thats-a-spicey-meatball/

Comment: @Mari-LouA -        It was from an experienced  financial analyst (Bloomberg TV) who was referring to the big assets of a company. "There is a lot of pizza there". All people present were quite aware of the expression. I think as Hot Lick roughly put it, it was an expression used in US a few dacades ago.

Comment: Well, for crying out loud why didn't you say that in your question?!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - at least I inspired your new 'pizza' question.

Comment: The clip from chasly did, you can hear it being used :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, I am a bit surpised that most experienced user are  unfamiliar with the expression.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - what's the English for the Italian expression "Tanta roba!"? There is a lot of pizza! comes close to it.

Comment: "shitload" is close to "tanta roba" but it depends on the context. If we're speaking about a women who is particularly curvaceous, some might exclaim "cor" or "phwoar" something like that. The "that's a lot of pizza", I would never say referring to a woman. The fact you heard Bloomberg say it, says something about the demographics.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'd not use to refer to woman either. I nice expression to be aware of, though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26876/discussion-on-question-by-josh61-thats-a-lot-of-pizza).

Answer (score 3):

***Early Google Books sightings of 'that's a lot of pizza'***

It is certainly possible that, as Hot Licks suggests in a comment above, the initial occasion for the expression "That's a lot of pizza!" was an advertising campaign by a U.S. pizza outlet. But in a Google Books search, the earliest instance of the expression is an [advertisement for Data General's UNIX-based AViiON7000 computer system](https://books.google.com/books?id=7HYC6s0yBr4C&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22Now+that%27s+a+lot+of+pizza%22&source=bl&ots=GyPECNGX7I&sig=3azNbUuzavf79iXJZLs7XL8x3PU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS69nRkuLXAhUM2WMKHQLxCHAQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=%22Now%20that%27s%20a%20lot%20of%20pizza%22&f=false) that appeared in various issues of *CIO* and *Computerworld* magazines from April through October of 1991. The headline of the advertisement reads as follows:

> **For the price of one AViiON7000 you can save $4,000,000 (now that's a lot of pizza!)**

The ad may be playing on an earlier advertisement or tagline from a pizza parlor, but it probably also reflects the supposed centrality of pizza in the diets of early computer engineers and programmers: if you think of meals in terms of pizzas, it isn't a very big jump to thinking of cost savings in terms of pizza equivalents.

That pizza was widely (and semi-seriously) proclaimed to be the staff of life for computer professionals helps explain why pizza-box might have become a standard term for any piece of equipment used to raise the level of a computer monitor on a desk. For example, Eric Raymond, [*The New Hacker's Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=g80P_4v4QbIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Hacker%27s+Dictionary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjutJWwm-LXAhWE0FQKHRnNDM8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=pizza&f=false), third edition (1996) has these pizza-related terms:

> **pizza, ANSI standard** {CMU} Pepperoni and mushroom pizza. Coined allegedly because most pizzas ordered by CMU hackers during some period leading up to mid-1990 were of that flavor.
>
> ...
>
> **rotary debugger** *n.* {Commodore} Essential equipment for those late-night or early-morning debugging sessions. Mainly used as sustenance for the hacker. Comes in many decorator colors, such as Sausage, Pepperoni, and Garbage.

And from *The Oxford Dictionary of Computing*, sixth edition (2008):

> **pizza-box** (2008) A piece of equipment, such as a computer system box, whose dimensions are roughly in the same proportions and size as the cardboard boxes used to transport pizzas, ... Such an enclosure can be conveniently placed beneath a monitor on a desk.

---

***Instances of 'that's a lot of X' intended literally***

Of course, the expression "that's a lot of X [or Xs]," where X is a mass noun (or Xs is  plural noun), goes back very far indeed in English. Here are a few newspaper examples. From "[Caribbean Twelve Percents](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=FFR18820622.2.30&txq=%22that+is+a+lot+of%22)," in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Farmer's Review* (June 22, 1882):

> "Will you lend me a hundred pounds?"
>
> "Name of St. Iago, **that is a lot of money**," I answered.

And from "[Louis Hanitch Talks of West Superior as a Wheat Shipping Point](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85042588/1891-11-20/ed-1/seq-5/#words=%22that+is+a+lot+of%22)," in the *Bismarck [North Dakota] Weekly Tribune* (November 20, 1891):

> But the wheat question is the foremost just now. A week ago last Monday 1,600 cars of wheat were received, the next day 1,200 cars, and it is averaging about 1,200 a day. **That is a lot of wheat**. North Da­kota wheat is the best, and we want it, and it is only a question of time when we will get about all there is to get.

And likewise, from an [advertisement for Emery, Bird & Thayer](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86063624/1897-01-14/ed-1/seq-8/#words=%22that+is+a+lot+of%22) in the *Kansas City [Missouri] Daily Journal* (January 14, 1897):

> **A Mammoth Shirt Sale! 8,880 Shirts to Make Your Selection From.**
>
> Yes, **that IS a lot of Shirts**. But the makers of them wanted to clean up stock and made prices to us A HALF for part and part for about ONE-THIRD their market value.

---

***Instances of 'that's a lot of X' intended figuratively***

The big change introduced by expressions along the lines of "that's a lot of pizza" is that the expression is intended figuratively. Saved money isn't literally lots of pizza—but people understand it as being in some sense equivalent to lots of pizza. Thus, the implicit meaning of "that's a lot of pizza" in these instances is "that's **the equivalent of** a lot of pizza."

Figurative expressions of this type begin to show up in newspaper articles from the 1920s. For example, from "[Dixon Bowlers Win Tilt from DeKalb Teams](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=DKD19270113.1.5&txq=%22that+is+a+lot+of%22)" in the *DeKalb [Illinois] Daily Chronicle* (January 13, 1927):

> Peters was the star wood crasher [that is, bowler] of the Dixon outfit getting three games well over the 200 mark, and **that is a lot of wood** to crash in each game.

In other words, a score above 200 in a single game is equivalent to a lot of fallen bowling pins.

And from "[Motordom Marches On!](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=WAF19361121.2.17&txq=%22that+is+a+lot+of%22)" in the *[Des Moines, Iowa] Wallaces' Farmer & Iowa Homestead* (November 21, 1936):

> Total payrolls in automotive and allied plants rose from $216,000,000 for the 12 months ending August, 1933, to $627,000,000 for the corresponding period of 1936. Translated into farm language **that is a lot of potatoes**.

We can hardly doubt that a lot of potatoes in 1936 farm language is a lot of pizza (or a lot of double lattes, or a lot of Big Macs, or a lot of rides on the Cyclone) today.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard it in the UK. It might have been influenced by an advertising campaign such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N4nqRPcdlk).

Comment: True, most of over here didn't know what pizzas were until the late sixties / early seventies. I, and I bet most Brits, thought that Dean Martin was singing "The moon in the sky like a big _piece of_ pie, that's amore"